# JavaScript console.log are same with `map` method in array

Tags: javascript

```js
const get = function() {
  return {
    name: 'me'
  }
}
const array = Array(10).fill(get());
console.log(array);

array.map(item => {
  console.log('1', item);
  item.a = '555'
  console.log('2', item);
  return item;
})
```

As you see, I modify element in the array like this `item.a = '555'`. I might console.log will output like this:

```js
1 { name: 'me' } 
2 { name: 'me', a: '555' }
```

but, actually I got this:

```js
1 { name: 'me', a: '555' } 
2 { name: 'me', a: '555' }
```

How to understand this?

Comment: `get()` is only being called once; you only have a single object in memory, which you're mutating on every iteration. Use `Array.from` instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance Actually, My question is why console's output is same. not how to fill Array.

Comment: `console.log` is asynchronous, it's kinda weird - the objects you examine are checked *when examined*, not when logged (see new link)

Comment: because each item of array is ref to name object

Comment: you can do the test like this `array[0] === array[1]` it's gonna produce `true`